# Boolean least squares

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

For a spectrum estimation algorithm I need to find the best fitting linear combination of vectors to fit a target spectral distribution. So far, this works relatively well using the `lsqlin` optimizer in MATLAB. 
However, for the final application I would like to approximate/solve this problem for exclusively zeros and ones, meaning Ax=b solved for Boolean x.

Is there any way to parametrize `lsqlin` or another optimizer function for this purpose?

Comment: Some advanced maths with sparse solvers, or L0 regularization would work, but this is quite advanced maths (that i dont know how tos use)

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is just:

```
Solve Ax=b for x in {0,1}
```

then you can use a MIP solver (e.g. Matlab `intlinprog`). If the problem is over-constrained and you want a least squares solution:

```
Min w'w
S.t. Ax - b = w
x in {0,1} (binary variable)
w free variable
```

then you have a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) problem. There are good solvers for this such as Cplex and Gurobi (callable from Matlab). Also Matlab has a discussion about an [approximation scheme](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-quadratic-programming-portfolio-optimization.html) using `intlinprog`. Another idea is to replace the quadratic objective by a sum of absolute values. This can be formulated as linear MIP model.